# How can I display a webpage fullscreen and prevent any access to that machine?

Tags: windows

I need to display a webpage based dashboard for CI in our office. This needs to run fullscreen but all access to that machine (Windows XP) should be disabled.

I'd thought of using a screensaver to display the webpage but there doesn't seem to be any easy solution out there. There's also the Kiosk plugin for Firefox but it doesn't lock the machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Added kiosk tag since it's somewhat relevant

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the Clear Screensaver, which I last saw in the Windows 2000 resource kit available from Microsoft downloads.  You would set a screen saver password, open the browser to the right page, change to kiosk mode (F11) then let the screen lock.

Moving the mouse or pressing a key brings up the password prompt.  It times out if nothing is entered.

Comment: I really like this suggestion, it is exactly what I'm after. However, I don't have access to the resource kit on CD and the Clear Screensaver doesn't seem to be available for download anywhere. Any ideas as to where I could locate it?

Comment: If you know anyone who was subscribed to Microsoft Technet or MSDN about 5 years ago, if they kept the disks it will be on a Resource Kits CD.  That's the last place I saw it unfortunately.  It might have been included in a Win 2003 resource kit too.

Answer (score 0):

Won't removing keyboard and mouse after running a browser in full screen (like Opera) work?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to install ultravnc and use the option to disable user input. You could also use the F11 key to make the window full screen.

hope this helps.